# DB2:Add Column if not present

Tags: db2

I have a schema called backup and a table called test in that. I need to add a column to the table called Test1 if it is not present in the table. Can you please tell me how to do it?

The following query returns me back an error.

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
IF (NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1 FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE TABNAME ='TEST_TABLE' AND COLNAME = 'TEST2'))
THEN 
     ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE ADD TEST2 varchar(255);
END IF;
END
GO
```

The error I'm recieving is this:

```
[Error] Script lines: 1-8 --------------------------
 DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE ADD TEST;E = 'TEST2'))
THEN 
;<compound_return>, DRIVER=3.50.152
 Message: An unexpected token "ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE ADD TEST" was found following "E = 'TEST2'))
THEN 
".  Expected tokens may include:  "<compound_return>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.50.152
 Line: 5
```

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: This blog post might help you - http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/09/13/checking-for-the-existence-of-a-column-in-a-table-db2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not execute dynamic query inside procedure. Do it with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ASP.CHECKTEST
     DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 0
     MODIFIES SQL DATA
     LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
IF (NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1 FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE TABNAME ='TEST_TABLE' AND COLNAME = 'TEST2'))
THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ASP.TEST_TABLE ADD COLUMN TEST2 varchar(255)';
END IF; 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have DDL inside the SP because--

If a routine parses correctly, the engine has to store a package and populate umpteen tables in the system catalog, including dependencies between the routine and other database objects. It simply can't do that if the body of the SP contains references to objects that don't yet exist or that have variable names or that will be altered or that depend on earlier creates, drops or alters inside the SP.

If you put the same thing inside the PREP & EXECUTE then it becomes a dynamic statement and ignored during compile time.